# My ext4 file system actually contains 2/3 as much as df/tune2fs says it does. Why?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

I have a 45-ish-gig virtual drive connected to a VM as my root partition.

```
root@alang-web:~# df -h
Filesystem        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs             396M  5.6M  390M   2% /run
/dev/sda1          46G   41G  2.3G  95% /
tmpfs             2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1         148G   15G  126G  11% /mnt/data
cgmfs             100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
alang-web-backup  621G  256G  366G  42% /media/sf_alang-web-backup
tmpfs             396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1000
```

As you can see, it reports 41 gigs of 46 gigs used.

And then there's this:

```
root@alang-web:~# du -shx /
27G /
```

And this:

```
root@alang-web:~# tune2fs -l /dev/sda1
tune2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
...
Block count:              12058624
Reserved block count:     602931
Free blocks:              1209455
...
```

And going to init 1 and running a fsck -f / reports no errors of any kind.

Where the heck is that 41G - 27G = 14G of space that is supposedly being used but is not visible to du? It can't be doubly-hard-linked files, that would cause du to be HIGHER than df (and anyway I don't know what would be doing that). It can't be unlinked files that are still in use, I have rebooted multiple times and the numbers simply don't change much. Also there's this:

```
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NLINK    NODE NAME
php-fpm7.  992     root    3u   REG    8,1        0     0 1837559 /tmp/.ZendSem.dSWbfL (deleted)
mysqld    1020    mysql    4u   REG    8,1        0     0 1837551 /tmp/ibybXrs3 (deleted)
mysqld    1020    mysql    5u   REG    8,1        0     0 1837623 /tmp/ibVK2BUX (deleted)
mysqld    1020    mysql    6u   REG    8,1        0     0 1837628 /tmp/ibavDMmS (deleted)
mysqld    1020    mysql    7u   REG    8,1        0     0 1837629 /tmp/ib5MSHjH (deleted)
mysqld    1020    mysql   11u   REG    8,1        0     0 1837631 /tmp/ibf8ZvTB (deleted)
php-fpm7. 1067 www-data    3u   REG    8,1        0     0 1837559 /tmp/.ZendSem.dSWbfL (deleted)
php-fpm7. 1068 www-data    3u   REG    8,1        0     0 1837559 /tmp/.ZendSem.dSWbfL (deleted)
apache2   1088     root   40u   REG    8,1        0     0 1837632 /tmp/.ZendSem.3m0mZe (deleted)
apache2   1091 www-data   40u   REG    8,1        0     0 1837632 /tmp/.ZendSem.3m0mZe (deleted)
apache2   1092 www-data   40u   REG    8,1        0     0 1837632 /tmp/.ZendSem.3m0mZe (deleted)
apache2   1093 www-data   40u   REG    8,1        0     0 1837632 /tmp/.ZendSem.3m0mZe (deleted)
apache2   1094 www-data   40u   REG    8,1        0     0 1837632 /tmp/.ZendSem.3m0mZe (deleted)
apache2   1095 www-data   40u   REG    8,1        0     0 1837632 /tmp/.ZendSem.3m0mZe (deleted)
apache2   1275 www-data   40u   REG    8,1        0     0 1837632 /tmp/.ZendSem.3m0mZe (deleted)
apache2   1277 www-data   40u   REG    8,1        0     0 1837632 /tmp/.ZendSem.3m0mZe (deleted)
apache2   1278 www-data   40u   REG    8,1        0     0 1837632 /tmp/.ZendSem.3m0mZe (deleted)
```

Those are all the unlinked files that it lists for that file system currently. I don't know how big those are (perhaps the size is inaccurate for files that are unlinked, or perhaps those really are size-0 files that are being used for semaphores or something of the sort.) However, it seems kind of unlikely that they're 14 gigs.

Is there some subtlety of ext4 that I don't know about? I freely admit to being more familiar with ext3 and HFS+. Is this somehow sharing space with some other partition or something like that, and the command line tool df hasn't kept up with modern times? Is the drive just broken in a way fsck can't even detect, let alone fix?

Just to preempt one other suggestion:

```
root@alang-web:~# cat > /tmp/blar
adsf
root@alang-web:~# du -sh /tmp/*
4.0K    /tmp/blar
root@alang-web:~#
```

So no, du does not report actual file sizes, it reports the size on disk including padding out to the next largest block size.

Comment: Yup, so it is. It was some files that were hidden behind a mount point. I actually spent a good hour searching serverfault for answers before I posted this and couldn't find anything useful, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.